# Cannot conditional render in render method react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.submitQA = this.submitQA.bind(this);
  this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
  this.isSearched = this.isSearched.bind(this);
  this.answerSubmitted = this.answerSubmitted.bind(this);
  this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    answers: [],
    answer: '',
    searchTerm: '',
  }
}

reset() {
  console.log("reset");
}

render() {
  const answer = true;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="center">

        <form >
        Search:  <input type="text" onChange={this.onSearchChange}  /><br/>
        </form>

        <form onSubmit={this.submitQA}>
          Q & A:
          <input type="text" placeholder=" Course/Q/A"/>
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
        <span>{basicFormat}</span>
      </div>

      {
        this.state.answers.filter(this.isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map((item) => {
          return (
            if(answer) {
              this.reset;
            }
            <div>
              <form  onSubmit={this.answerSubmitted}>
                <text> {item} </text>
                <input type="text" placeholder="answer the question"/>
              </form>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why can't I use any logic in this render method? Keeps giving me unexpected token. Do not see anything wrong with it. Looked at some tutorials and they are doing the exact same thing but why is mine throwing me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included a Javascript `if` statement inside the return, mixed with the JSX.
 [Quoting the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx):

> `if` statements and `for` loops are not expressions in JavaScript, so they can't be used in JSX directly. Instead, you can put these in the surrounding code.

To fix the unexpected token error, move the `if` statement before the `return`:

```
{
  this.state.answers.filter(this.isSearched(this.state.searchTerm)).map((item) => {
    if(answer) {
      this.reset();
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <form  onSubmit={this.answerSubmitted}>
          <text> {item} </text>
          <input type="text" placeholder="answer the question"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

I would also recommend that you perform the mapping before the return in the `render` function. That way, the rendering is more clearly separated from the data manipulation.

```
render() {
  const answer = true;
  const answerForms = this.state.answers
    .filter(this.isSearched(this.state.searchTerm))
    .map((item) => {
      if (answer) {
        this.reset()
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.answerSubmitted}>
            <text> {item} </text>
            <input type="text" placeholder="answer the question" />
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="center">
        <form >
          Search:  <input type="text" onChange={this.onSearchChange} /><br />
        </form>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitQA}>
          Q & A:
          <input type="text" placeholder=" Course/Q/A" />
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
        <span>{basicFormat}</span>
      </div>
      {answerForms}
    </div>
  )
}
```